# htaccess redirect with multi params

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to config .htaccess to redirect URL:

> http://domain.com/banners/images/?id=123&name=johnmartin&filename=17700_120X600.png

to new URL:

> http://domain.com/uploads/image/17700_120X600.png

I tried to config like below:

```
 RedirectMatch 301 ^/banners/images/?id=$1&name=$2&filename=$3    /uploads/image/$3
```

But it not run.
How I can fix it?

Comment: `Redirect` or `Rewrite`?

Comment: php != .htaccess, please don't tag it with php

Answer (score 0):

To match against query strings, you need to use mod_rewrite :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=123&name=johnmartin&filename=17700_120X600.png$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^banners/images/?$  http://domain.com/uploads/image/17700_120X600.png [NC,QSA,L,R]
```

For dynmic query string values, try

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)&name=([^&]+)&filename=([0-9]+)_([0-9]+)X([0-9]+).png$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^banners/images/?$  http://domain.com/uploads/image/%3_%4X%5.png [NC,QSA,L,R]
```